# The attribute nativeQuery is undefined for the annotation type Query

Tags: jpa

Quiero crear un query native y Eclipse me dice Change to name   en nativeQuery  The attribute nativeQuery is undefined for the annotation type Query

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface IRepository extends JpaRepository<Menu, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM menus   WHERE id = 1",  nativeQuery = true);
    Menu getMenu();
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Parece que estas planteando de forma incorrecta la query, aunque la clase tiene varios problemas, vamos por partes.

Para solucionar el problema que planteas debes dar un alias al objeto que quieres seleccionar de esta forma:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface IRepository extends JpaRepository<Menu, Integer> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM menus m   WHERE m.id = :idMenu",  nativeQuery = true);
  Menu getMenu(Integer idMenu);
 }
```

Aunque no lo preguntas, utilizas la anotacion @transactional cuando declaras la clase del repositorio lo cual no esta usado de manera correcta, el correcto querer realizar los accesos a la BBDD de forma transaccional pero la anotacion deberias realizarla en los metodos de servicio que hagan uso de este repositorio, espero haber sido claro.

Para terminar la query podria aprovecharse mejor si tal y como te indico en la respuesta le pasas un parametro para que reciba una id, te tal forma que es más reutilizable.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné y puedo crear un nativeQuery. El problema era de dependencias.Y en los imports:
org springframework data jpa repository JpaRepository,
org springframework data jpa repository Query,
org springframework data jpa repository query Param,
org springframework data jpa repository stereotype Repository

Comment: Y como hace otro usuario para saber como se soluciona esto, si en lugar de la solucion escribiste un comentario diciendo que ya lo solucionaste????